# Cannot re-install apache 2.2 services on XP through xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm trying to experiment with xampp. After having some space issues, I wanted to move my xampp install onto another drive (d:). However I have the apache 2.2 services in XP services which are still pointing to my original c: install. I only see how to start and stop. I'm hoping just removing the service will fix my issues.

So the question is two-part 1) how do i remove the service 2) based on this info can i simply reinstall afterwards to get the services running?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a command prompt execute:

sc delete **service**

Where **service** be Apache and mysql.

Then go into your xampp control panel and check the little svc boxes. That will make them services again.

Be sure to run the "setup_xampp.bat" script in the root of your xampp server! You must do this each time your servers change directory (this feature is useful if you put your servers on a USB drive).

Good luck :)